# Why is it that, when accepting an answer, it does not automatically receive an upvote?

Tags: discussion

Not sure if I'm clear so I'll explain :-)

If the person asking a question accepts a given answer, why is this answer not upvoted at the same time ? I find it "strange" to have question with accepted answers with 0 points, with no upvote/downvote at all.

This does not happen very much at Programmers I think, but I've seen it a lot on the main Stack Overflow.

So, has this been though of before ? Is it by design ?

Comment: This has been thought of before, [asked about on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/when-you-accept-an-answer-should-you-also-vote-it-up) and [status declined by the team on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting).

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thanks for the link Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by design.

Accepting an answer is independent of voting up (or down).

Don't forget that an answer might not be useful but it still might be the answer solves the problem for the OP. The answer might be "you can't do that" (for example) which isn't really that useful (even if it is true) but if it's really the case then the OP might accept it.

Also, don't forget a new user can't up-vote until they get 15 reputation, whereas they can *always* accept an answer.

Comment: I didn't know about the 15 reputation barrier, that effectively may explain why these situations happen. Thanks! So, I'm going to upvote AND accept your answer :-)

Comment: I down voted because "you can't do that" isn't really that useful (even if it is true)